# How to restart remote win 2008 server machine with IP address

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008, reboot, remote-access, remote-control

I need to restart remote machine for which Ip address and UserName/Password are known to me.

**Tried but not working :-** The remote machine does not have PowerShell enabled because my "Restart-Computer " fails. I could not use nbtstat command because I don't know the computer name. Also tried [technet ms blog](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770416.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [similar stackoverflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526596/restart-remote-client-machine) but both needs computer name which I don't know.

**Details :-** The remote computer OS is Windoows 2008 server edition.

PS. Earlier asked this question at Stackoverflow and now moved here based on community suggestion.

Comment: Try remote desktop, login and shut down using start menu?

Comment: @mt025 Could you share any detail who to do this having IP address and credentials. I want to restart because nothing is visible when login with RDP.

Comment: Are you on the same LAN as the remote machine? Are there any firewalls between you and it?

Comment: @Sankalp What do you mean nothing is visible? What do you see? If you are able to login, you should be able to shutdown/restart? You can always do "shutdown -r -t 0" in command prompt to restart

Comment: Can you not just run the remote shutdown command like so to complete the task: **o{[|||||||||]]::;;::;;::;;;::;;::>** `SHUTDOWN /M <IP ADDRESS> /R /F /T 01`.... What error message do you see when you try to run a remote shutdown with that syntax or something similar?

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT It says "computer name is not valid or remote shutdown is not supported.....contact system admin.<53>

Comment: Do you have physical or remote RDP access to this server? Do you have local admin credentials to authenticate remotely or locally to this server to perform admin operations such as remote shutdowns? You may need to open up WMI and RCP ports on this server or enable the remote administration rule or whatever it is called. Think about and research some of all that which I mentioned and report back when you get a chance if that helps you any.  I think TCP port 135 for WMI\RCP inbound and outbound or remote administration may be needed. At the Server 2008 level open all that up, test, etc.